# Run Ubuntu server on raspberry Pi 2

Tags: 14.04, server, webserver

Can I use Ubuntu server with a Raspberry Pi 2? I plan to use it as a headless web server. How can I install Ubuntu server on the sd card?

Comment: This is something you can use for RPi https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#snappy-raspi2

Comment: in addition to @mbiber's suggestion, consider asking something *similar* on [raspberrypi.se], but try not to [cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/310919).

Comment: this is answered at the Raspberry Pi SE-site: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/142/23017

Answer (score 0):

Currently Ubuntu server exists only for AMD64 architecture. Raspberry however is an ARM device, and for that purpose exits snappy. It is however somewhat different, it doesn't use apt but rather uses snappy, the new transactional package management. According to Mark Shuttleworth with 16.04 however there should be apt and dpkg available for snappy available. Personally, I've been using it with docker. But as of now there is lack of packages for ARM architecture. You can try Arch linux for raspberry but as of now, Ubuntu Snappy and Mate are two best choices the Ubuntu community can offer

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into Raspbian Jessie Lite, which is a no-GUI version of Raspbian. Being based on Debian, it is pretty close to Ubuntu and APT is ready to go. Also, Raspbian is the best supported OS for the Pi, so there's no shortage of help on how to optimize it for server usage.